# PHP and mysql update statement

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a code that update some of the values in one of my row in the a table. 
The code works but no as well as i wanted. It changes all values of the rows instead of changing just the one that I wanted to change. 
For example if i'm trying change the price of one of the items, by filling the price field in the form and leaving the rest blank. 
But instead of updating the price only it updates the whole table with blank values, which means all the information from the table 
will have gone and I only wanted to change the price. How can fix this?
Thanks
Here is my code:

```
include("misc.inc");
$id = $_GET['id'];
$db = 0;
$db = mysql_connect($db_host . ":" . $db_port, $db_user, $db_pwd);
if ($db == 0) {die("Cannot connect, Error <b>" . mysql_errno() . "</b>: " . mysql_error());};
echo "Database connection has been established successfully<br />\n";
mysql_query("USE " . $db_db);
if (mysql_errno() != 0) {die("Cannot USE database, Error <b>" . mysql_errno() . "</b>: " . mysql_error());};
echo "Database has been selected successfully<br />\n";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])):

$itemName = $_POST ['itemName'];
$item_Description = $_POST ['item_Description'];
$price = $_POST ['price'];
$contactName = $_POST ['contactName'];
$phone = $_POST ['phone'];
$email = $_POST ['email'];
$website =$_POST ['website']; 

$sql = "UPDATE items SET
        itemName = '$itemName', 
        email = '$email', 
        item_description ='$item_Description', 
        price = '$price', 
        contactName = '$contactName', 
        phone ='$phone', 
        website ='$website' 
        WHERE items.itemID='$id'";

if (@mysql_query($sql)) {
   echo('<p>Item editted successfully!</p>');
   } else {
   echo('<p>Error editting item!<br />'.
        'Error <b>' . mysql_errno() . '</b>'. mysql_error() . '</p>');
   }
?>
<p><a href="<? $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method = "POST"></a></p>
<p><a href="items.php">Return to Front Page</a></p>
</ul>
```

Comment: It looks like $id is never defined anywhere. As it is what limits your update query to one row, I would recommend ensuring that $id is set properly.

Comment: $id has not been declared. Could this be the problem?

Comment: I suspect he means "rows" when he writes table.

Comment: This code has a serious injection vulnerability. It's enough to pass "www.example.com'; DROP TABLE items; --" as the website POST parameter, and your database is fried. Use mysql_real_escape_string or MySQLi with bind parameters.

Answer (score 2):

There's four options (ok, maybe more ;-) )

1. Fill all empty variable with the current values of the database record. That way, fields that are not changed, effectivly update the field to the same value
2. Like above, but put the current values in the form. You can then choose to modify the values or explicitly clear them
3. Build a specific query, updating only the fields you want to change. Only the fields included in the SET clause of your statement are updated.
4. Use a trigger to prevent a value being updated to null. Make it use the current value. This seems like the solution in 1 and 2, but has the advantage that you do not overwrite values of others when more than one is editing the same record.

I would choose 2 or 3.

- 2 because it allows you to edit or clear the fields.
- 3 because it makes you update only the relevant fields. You can easily detect if any change is made at all and skip the update alltogether if there's not.

Answer (score 2):

1. `$id` is undefined.  Add a line like `$id =$_POST ['id'];` to solve this.
2. At the end of the UPDATE query, add `LIMIT 1` to ensure only one row is updated
3. **Extra credit**: Sanitize/escape the POST data to prevent SQL injection attacks. :p

Comment: #3 yes, don't consider it optional to use: `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Answer (score 0):

You could dynamically create the SQL query by looping through the fields and only including references to fields that require changing.

**NOTE:** I haven't tested this and you should include data cleansing to prevent SQL injection. You would also need to handle the possibility that no fields have been updated.

```
<?php

include("misc.inc"); 
$id = $_GET['id']; 
$db = 0; 
$db = mysql_connect($db_host . ":" . $db_port, $db_user, $db_pwd); 
if ($db == 0) {die("Cannot connect, Error <b>" . mysql_errno() . "</b>: " . mysql_error());}; 
echo "Database connection has been established successfully<br />\n"; 
mysql_query("USE " . $db_db); 
if (mysql_errno() != 0) {die("Cannot USE database, Error <b>" . mysql_errno() . "</b>: " . mysql_error());}; 
echo "Database has been selected successfully<br />\n"; 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])): 

$fields = array('itemName','item_Description', 'price', 'contactName', 'phone', 'email', 'website');

$updates = '';

foreach ($fields as $key) {
    if (isset($_POST['$key'])) {
              $value = $_POST['$key'];
        if ($updates != '') {
            $updates = $key . " = \'" . $value . "\'";
        } else {
            $updates = $updates . ", " . $key . " = \'" . $value . "\'";
        }
    }
}

if ($updates != '') {

    $sql = "UPDATE items SET $updates WHERE items.itemID='$id'";

    if (@mysql_query($sql)) { 
        echo('<p>Item editted successfully!</p>'); 
    } else { 
        echo('<p>Error editting item!<br />Error <b>' . mysql_errno() . '</b>'. mysql_error() . '</p>'); 
    }
}

?>
<p><a href="<? $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST"></a></p> 
<p><a href="items.php">Return to Front Page</a></p> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code but It didn't work, i'm sure it was something simple that i needed to changed. instead i used this startement: `$product = mysql_fetch_object($result);` and I put the variable in the forms so it displays the old records when the user want to update the rows. something like this `<b>Phone Number: </b><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"value="<?php echo $product->phone; ?>" size="20" maxlength="255"/><br /><br />` Thanks for your help